# Create a symbolic Link into a Folder that doesn't exist

Tags: symlink

I am trying to create about 100,000 symbolic links.  The location of the link is in a folder which I want to define at the same time as I create the link.

For example

`ln -s File1 FolderA/File1`

Once I figure out if this is possible, I'd like to just use a loop to create all the links.  I haven't been able to find a way to do this (apologies if it is trivial).

Comment: Are you trying to do `mkdir -p FolderA/File1 && ln -s -T File1 FolderA/File1` for each in a set of directories.

Comment: I am not sure what -T does, but FolderA/File1 will just point to the original File1.  And FolderA does not exist at the time of initiating the command.

Comment: Yes the File one will not point to the correct File1, but if we fix that bit. Is it what you want to do?

Comment: yes, I think what you describe is my goal

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
original_dir="$(pwd)"
mkdir -p FolderA
cd FolderA
for file in "${original_dir}"/*
do
  ln -s -t . "$file"
done
```

Not tested

Comment: Use `for ` instead of `foreach` if using bash or sh

Comment: @GMaster sorry my bad. It would have been OK for you to fix it.